# Rails - Trouble with AJAX Create Method and Response

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, email

New to rails, so please excuse the noob question. Having some trouble with capturing e-mails via AJAX.

**Desired Functionality:**
I'm creating a landing page for my site where we capture e-mails ("Leads" = object/model). I want to capture the e-mails asynchronously, then display a thank you message to the user. If user enters an invalid e-mail, I want to ask them to input a correct e-mail.

**What I've Got Working**
I can correctly capture the e-mail and perform validation via AJAX. If I enter an invalid e-mail then click "submit", it is not shown on /leads/index. If I enter an invalid e-mail, it is shown on /leads/index.

**What I Don't Have Working**
I have not figured out how to get any sort of response back to the user. All I want to do is change the text of an h3 (class="results") element if the save was successful.

**My Code**

landing.html.erb:

```
        <h3 class="results">Give us your e-mail and we'll send you an invite to beta when it's ready.</h3>

        <%= form_for(:lead, remote: true, :url => {:controller => 'leads', :action => 'create'}, :html => {:class => 'form-inline emailForm'}) do |f| %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label(:email, 'E-mail', class: 'sr-only') %>
            <%= f.text_field(:email, {:id => 'submitEmail2', :class=> 'form-lg', :placeHolder => 'E-mail Address'}) %>
          </div>
          <%= submit_tag("Sounds Good", {:id => 'submitEmail2', :class => 'btn btn-success btn-lg'}) %>
        <% end %>
```

leads_controller.rb

```
 class LeadsController < ApplicationController

  layout false
  #respond_to :html, :js

  def index
    @leads = Lead.order("created_at ASC")
  end

  def show
  end

  def new

  end

  def create
    @lead = Lead.new(lead_params) #Create a new object without form parameters

  end

  def edit
  end

  def delete
  end


  private
    def lead_params
      params.require(:lead).permit(:email)
    end
end
```

create.js.erb

```
$('h3.results').html("");

//If I remove this code, it works
<% if @lead.save? %>
    $("h3.results").html("Thank you! We'll let you know when it's ready."));
    $('.emailForm').hide();
<% else %>
    $("h3.results").html("Invalid E-mail. Please try again!"));
<% end %>
```

If I remove the last bit of code in create.js.erb, everything works and the text in the h3 gets removed. What is wrong with the save statement? Am I doing the save in the correct section of my code, or should it be in the controller?

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Your use of terminology does not suggest a newbie. You've had coding experience somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks! A hodge-podge of experience in a bunch of different languages, on an off for the last few years. Finally getting back into developing full-time.

Comment: Stick with Rails and you'll grow quite far I think!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> New to rails

Welcome!

---

> I have not figured out how to get any sort of response back to the user

[`Ajax`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) responses are *always* sent back on completion of the request.

How you handle it is up to you.

You'll be able to see the responses by looking at the `network` tab of your `devloper console` in your browser. In chrome, you'll be able to `right-click > Inspect Element > Network`:

[image]

You'll be able to see the request being sent when you submit your form.

---

> it is not shown on /leads/index

The problem you have is your `save` functionality.

As mentioned by `cweston`, you're best saving the record in the controller action itself (this has direct access to the model):

```
def create
  @lead = Lead.new lead_params
  @lead.save
  respond_to do |format|
     format.js #-> app/views/leads/create.js.erb
  end
end
```

This will allow you to use the following ([`new_record?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/new_record%3F)):

```
  #app/views/leads/create.js.erb
  <% message = @lead.new_record? "Invalid Email. Please try again!" : "Thank you! We'll let you know when it's ready" %>
  $("h3.results").html("<%=j message %>");

  <% unless @lead.new_record? %>
    $('.emailForm').fadeOut(500, function(){
       $(this).remove();
    });
  <% end %>
```

This should give you the ability to manage your HTML elements in the DOM.

---

**Response**

In terms of your response, the fact you're using the inbuilt server-side JS is great; I applaud that.

The *other* way you could handle your response would be to use client-side Ajax. You don't need to do this, as you're using the Rails UJS driver, but here's how you'd do it anyway:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("submit", "form#new_lead", function(e) {
   $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr("action"),
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
          // stuff here
      },
      error: function(data) {
         // stuff here
      }
   }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are getting an error on the line:

```
<% if @lead.save? %>
```

You should be performing the save in the controller:

```
def create
  lead = Lead.new(lead_params)
  @saved = lead.save
end
```

*Note the use of `save` not `save?`*

You can then test if `@lead.save` was successful in your view with `@saved`:

```
$('h3.results').html("");

<% if @saved %>
  $("h3.results").html("Thank you! We'll let you know when it's ready."));
  $('.emailForm').hide();
<% else %>
  $("h3.results").html("Invalid E-mail. Please try again!"));
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you explain why I have to use `save` and not `save`? Is declaring the variable in the controller best rails practice?

Unfortunately, it looks like the error is even more noobish than I thought. The issue was the double parenthesis before the semicolon at the end of the lines where I declare h3 -_-

Comment: Otherwise you would get a "NoMethodError (undefined method `save?' for #Lead<0x007fbe31320f18>". This how the save method is defined, you can view the [documentation here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/save)

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**
I'm an idiot. The error was because of the double parenthesis at the end of my `$('h3.results')` calls.